How to debug a running container service in VS Code?
I have a containerized architecture where each service runs in a different container, and I have a Docker Compose file for the same. I want to debug one of these services named api. The code is written in Python. I know how to attach to this container but am facing problem in debugging it.
Earlier I used PyCharm Pro, which had the option to debug on Docker Compose, does VS Code have a similar functionality?
These are the running services of which I want to debug the api
When I do the docker compose down build up, it creates a whole copy of the code and runs it.
There had been some solutions explaining how I can add debugpy to my file but it doesn't seem to work for me and the API container is shutting down throwing the error:
Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
2024-09-16T10:32:29.839664068Z 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
2024-09-16T10:32:29.839666963Z 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.

I don't want to disturb the modules and want to debug my running service in as few changes as possible because this is the production code. I want a VS Code alternative for the debug on Docker Compose and then selecting a service in PyCharm Professional.
